# Get children using viewChildren with nested directives

Tags: angular, angular-directive, viewchild

I am trying to implement some features in my angular application. I have created a parent directive `appParent` and two other directives `appChildAbc` and `appChildXyz`.

What I want to do is that whenever I have the `appParent` directive applied on an element, I want to check for its child elements (native HTML elements in the same component) and apply some logic to these child elements.

After much search and struggle I have found a way to do it using the `ViewContainerRef` in `ParentDirective` and `@ViewChildren` in `AppComponent`, but I had to use `((this.viewContainerRef as any)._view.nodes)`, which does not look like the right way to do it.

Is there any other way to get the reference of `Child Elements` in the parent directive ??

Sample stackblitz  [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-directive-ng)

Feel free to fork the code and update as necessary. Thanks in advance

### Parent Directive

```js
export class ParentDirective {
  constructor(private vcr: ViewContainerRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log((this.vcr as any)._view.nodes);
    let lists = (this.vcr as any)._view.nodes.filter(
      x => x.constructor.name === "QueryList"
    );
    lists.forEach(list => {
      list.toArray().forEach(x => {
        if (x.constructor.name === "ChildXyzDirective")
          x.elementRef.nativeElement.style.background = "red";
        else x.elementRef.nativeElement.style.background = "green";
        console.log(x);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

### App.component.ts

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  @ViewChildren(ChildXyzDirective) xyzChildren: QueryList<ChildXyzDirective>;
  @ViewChildren(ChildAbcDirective) abcChildren: QueryList<ChildAbcDirective>;
}
```

### App.component.html

```html
<div appParent>
  Parent div directive
  <div appChildAbc>
    Abc Child directive 1
  </div>
  <div appChildAbc>
    Abc Child directive 2
  <div appChildXyz>
    Xyz Child directive 1
  </div>
  <div appChildXyz>
    Xyz Child directive 2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `@ContentChildren` decorator to query child directive

*ParentDirective*

```js
@Directive({
  selector: "[appParent]"
})
export class ParentDirective {

 @ContentChildren(ChildXyzDirective,{descendants: true}) 
 xyzChildren : QueryList<ChildXyzDirective>;

 @ContentChildren(ChildAbcDirective,{descendants: true}) 
 abcChildren : QueryList<ChildAbcDirective>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {  

      this.abcChildren.forEach(e => {
        e.elementRef.nativeElement.style.background = "red";
      });

      this.xyzChildren.forEach(e => {
        console.log(e)
        e.elementRef.nativeElement.style.background = "green";
      });

  }
}
```

> **[ContentChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren#description)** Use to get the QueryList of elements or directives from the content DOM. Any time a child element is added, removed, or
>   moved, the query list will be updated, and the changes observable of
>   the query list will emit a new value.

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-directive-ng-qvr6x3)

Comment: Awesome !! I had tried using `@ContentChildren` , but `{descendants: true}` was missing. Thanks

Comment: Thank you!!  After trying everything, `{descendants: true}` is what did the trick!!